# How to determine why gitbash cannot find commands

Tags: python, shell, git-bash

Just yesterday gitbash was working completely fine, and now for some reason all of the commands that it would normally recognize involving python are "not found."

I checked the file folders using 'ls' and all the necessary files were there, but given that I don't understand the inner workings of gitbash I am unsure as to how to diagnose what is causing it to be unable to recognize python and python related commands.

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps adding python binary to [PATH environment variable](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)?

Comment: I already have a python path created.

Comment: Not `PYTHONPATH`, just `PATH`. Try typing `which python` in a normal console and see what's the result.

Comment: It said "which: no python in (long list of directories and subdirectories)"